Query maximum line width that OpenGL supports?
I there a programmatical way (e.g. OpenGL command) to determine the maximal line width IN PIXELS supported by my GPU's OpenGL implementation?
I recently worked with a OpenGL buffer with width ~50000 pixels and got bad results. Decomposing the image with smaller line widths solved the problem.  However to robustly implement this solution I would need to know what the maximal width the particular GPU supports.

As stated by the documentation for glLineWidth, the maximum sizes can be queried with
GLfloat values[2];
glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, values);

or
GLfloat values[2];
glGetFloatv(GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, values);

depending on whether antialiasing is enabled or not. Both commands store two values indicating the minimum and maximum supported width for lines.

The command you refer to (glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE) returns (on my hardware) the pair (1.0, 10), which relates to the rendered scene. After some investigation I use glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE) which gives me 1 << 14.  Looks right and verified by experiment.   I must remark that the macro GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE should be
